# How can i check for RegistryKey permissions like ReadKey or FullControl in .NET?

Tags: c#, security, permissions, registrykey

I want to check that I have permissions on a RegistryKey for example can I read values and write values. This blog enumerates permissions

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/01/06/509867.aspx

How can I go from GetAccessControl() to knowing that I have for example FullControl?

Comment: What is your backup plan when you find out that you don't have access?

Comment: Catching the exception is OK. I had thought there might be a quick test on the access rules but nothing like .CanRead or .CanFullControl jumped out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no managed code for this. 
you could use a dllimport and invoke[CheckAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384911%28VS.85%29.aspx) but i prefer just accessing the registry and handling the exception (if any)

Comment: Microsoft woulf prefer it if you wouldn't use the Registry at all... Probably why they do not support all functionality in their .NET framework.

Comment: +1 avoid registry.  If for whatever reason you need it, just catch and handle SecurityException

Comment: Thank you. Catching exception will do. Those GetAccessControl classes look more complicated than i hoped for.