# How to check if i have permission to write to a registry key

Tags: c#, error-handling, registry

In C#, how can i check if i permission to write to a registry key?

---

I am trying to store a value in a registry key:

```
try
{
    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Contoso\SQMClient", true))
    {
       if (key != null)
          key.SetValue("UserId", sUserId);
    }
}
catch (System.Security.SecurityException e)
{
   //Not allowed to set UserId. No biggie.
}
```

Except that the **`OpenSubKey`** throws an exception:

```
System.Security.SecurityException occurred
   HResult=-2146233078
   Message=Requested registry access is not allowed.
```

i don't want to intentionally throw an exception. How can i validate my permission to a registry key before i attempt to open in; in order to prevent an exception from being thrown?

**Note**: It may, or may not, involve [`key.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7fwef5z.aspx). It also may not be possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `GetAccessControl` throws an exception if you can't read the key itself, but you can use it to check if you have write permissions.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947526/how-can-i-check-for-registrykey-permissions-like-readkey-or-fullcontrol-in-net

Comment: Attempting to open the key and catching the exception seems like the easiest and most appropriate way of doing this. It certainly avoids any possible race conditions. And the performance cost is likely to be irrelevant; you only open the key once, therefore only catch one exception. Plus, this code is probably run as a result of user action, and users are slow in computer terms.